# Display raw JSON with non-ascii characters

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, decoding

I'm having trouble displaying raw JSON data in the terminal, using Python3. I get the json as a response from urllib:

```
r = urlopen(request)
response = r.read()
```

The result is a byte string `b"..."`, part of which contains non-ASCII characters like `b"Chybn\\u00e9 heslo"`, which should give me this `"Chybné heslo"`.

But I don't know how to decode it to display `"Chybné heslo"`, if I do:

```
print(b"Chybn\\u00e9 heslo".decode('utf-8'))
```

I just get `"Chybn\u00e9 heslo"`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unicode-escape` codec:

```
byte_str = b"Chybn\u00e9 heslo"
print(byte_str.decode('unicode-escape')) # Chybné heslo
```

---

The reason of your problem is that in byte-strings `\u00e9` is not a unicode code point.
It's just a sequence of bytes:

```
>>> len(b'\u00e9') # whereas len('\u00e9') == 1
6 

>>> [b for b in b'\u00e9']
[92, 117, 48, 48, 101, 57]
```

These bytes are also UTF-8 bytes, so when you decode them with this encoding you get the corresponding sequence of characters:

```
>>> b'\u00e9'.decode('utf-8')
'\\u00e9'

>>> [chr(b) for b in b'\u00e9'] # decoding in 'byte-by-byte' mode
['\\', 'u', '0', '0', 'e', '9']
```

---

Also note that `\\` and `\` are equivalent in some strings (*for more information check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)*).
For example:

```
>>> b'\\u' == b'\u'
True
>>> b'\\u00e9' == b'\u00e9'
True
>>> b'\\n' == b'\n'
False
```

```
>>> '\\u00e9' == '\u00e9'
False

>>> '\\z' == '\z' 
True
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I needed. Also thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really a valid JSON string response, it should have double quotes around the string, and it this case is an entirely ASCII response with Unicode codepoints represented as JSON escape codes.  You can use the `json` module to decode it.  This will handle much more complex JSON responses as well, containing lists and key/value pairs:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(b'"Chybn\\u00e9 heslo"')
'Chybné heslo'
```

Also look into the `requests` module (3rd party), which will decode JSON for you:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
>>> r.text
'{\n   "time": "06:58:22 AM",\n   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1508914702539,\n   "date": "10-25-2017"\n}\n'
>>> r.json()
{'time': '06:58:22 AM', 'milliseconds_since_epoch': 1508914702539, 'date': '10-25-2017'}
>>> D = r.json()
>>> D['time']
'06:58:22 AM'
```

Comment: The problem was: I didn't need to decode json, but to display it raw,  as it is, not parsed as python dict, with double quotes and original ordering. But thank you for your help.